# NodeJs multiple reply for requests after connecting to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

when my device is disconnected from server or device don't have internet connection, after emitting multiple socket to server that cause of reply to all sockets after connecting to server

for example:

1- client disconnected from server, i click multiple on button to emit data for example 10 click as request

2- after connecting client to server, server reply on 10 response

how can i manage this process?

Comment: What do you mean by `manage`? Do you want to only emit 1 of the events, or do them at an interval, or something else?

Comment: @JayGould that is an interval requests

Answer (score 1):

problem resolved, Thanks to [@farhadamjady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7104389/farhadamjady)

```
var mySocket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.4:8080/backend_app', {transports: ['websocket'], reconnection: true});

mySocket.on('connect', function () {
    mySocket.sendBuffer=[]
    console.log('Connected!');
});
```